# Background image scaled to html document height

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am having trouble scaling a repeating image to the height of the document in html.
I can clearly see how large the html element is using the inspector.

I have set the div's height to 100rem, which should scale it to 100% of the height of the root element (which as far as I understand is the html element).

CSS:

```
#left-buildings{
    left: 0;
    float:left;
}

.buildings{
    height: 100rem;
    position: absolute;
    width: 5%;
    top: 0;
    background-image: url(../media/images/city-side-seamless.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="buildings" id="left-buildings"> </div>
    <div class="buildings" id="right-buildings"> </div>
```

The problem is, it does not scale to the correct size.

[screenshot showing that the element is not spanning the height of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGq9D.jpg)

Comment: 1 rem means default font-size. In most browsers, 1 rem is 16px default.

Comment: So I think you mean 100vh.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad XD.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the height to 100vh.
rem is the relative to font-size of the root element

Comment: The thing is, the buildings need to extend beyond the viewport height. 

Setting it to the veiwport height makes them extend to about the middle of the html document. 

I tried to use rem, because they need to be the height of the entire html document. 

If you hover over the html tag in the inspector, you can see that it covers the entire page, and not just the part that is visible in the vewport.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the images as an img tag inside the divs, and then you can just style them to 100% height.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around the problem but setting the height of the buildings to a measurement in pixels that fits length of the page. This prevents the buildings form scaling when one zooms in on the page. Quite conveniently, it also lets the ends "overflow" and doesn't extend the page height when you zoom. Not too sure why that happens, but I'm not complaining XD.